# How do you programmatically configure and present a popover on iPhone in iOS 8+

Tags: ios, objective-c

How can you present a UIViewController in a popover on iPhone (all sizes and orientations), in iOS 8 using only Objective-C code, no Story Boards or other Interface Builder artifacts.

Answer (score 22, accepted):

In iOS 8, you can configure any view controller to be displayed as a popover, like so:

```
UIViewController* controller = ...; // your initialization goes here

// set modal presentation style to popover on your view controller
// must be done before you reference controller.popoverPresentationController
controller.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
controller.preferredContentSize = CGSizeMake(150, 300);

// configure popover style & delegate
UIPopoverPresentationController *popover =  controller.popoverPresentationController;
popover.delegate = controller;
popover.sourceView = sourceView;
popover.sourceRect = CGRectMake(150,300,1,1);
popover.permittedArrowDirections = UIPopoverArrowDirectionAny;

// display the controller in the usual way
[self presentViewController:controller animated:YES completion:nil];
```

So that it displays as a popover on iPhone, add this to the `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` delegate of the popover (that you set above):

```
- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;
}
```